# Java CPU profiling tool with API for data collection and reporting

Tags: software-development, java, profiling

I am looking for **CPU profiling** tool for Java.
The data collection agent must

- supports multiple platform (windows 32 and 64bit, Linux 64bit)
- should   able to deploy on tens of machines without licensing problem
- **Must   have Java API** to start, stop profiling, filter applied classes, and dump
  data to some location
- preferably pure Java

The analysis/reporting agent

- **Must have Java API to analyze data** , say a report on top 100% functions or how much time spend on specific method, how many times a method was called.
- Okay to be platform dependent
- Okay to be commercial license

I have considered yourkit. Data collection is possible with API, but does not have a programmatic way to analyse the capture data(am I wrong?)